# Pattern for responding with async result

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to get the following example working:

```
def asyncTest = Action {

    val willBeInt = Future {
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        100
    }

    willBeInt.onComplete({
        case Success(value) => Ok(s"Value = $value")
        case Failure(e) => Failure(e)
    })
}
```

But I am getting an error about overloading a method:

```
Overloaded method value [apply] cannot be applied to  (Unit)
```

---

I'm coming from a background in NodeJS and am struggling to figure out how these callbacks are supposed to work while simultaneously returning a result to appease the method signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of `Action` as a function that returns a promise, rather than as a function that accepts a callback. In scala terminology, you'll be returning a `Future`. Play's internals will be calling `onComplete` (or something similar) on their own (analagous to a javascript Promise's `then` function).

Specifically, your compilation error is due to the fact that `onComplete` returns `Unit`, when the `Action` block is expecting you to return a `Future`. You can use `map` to transform your `willBeInt` future into what Play is looking for:

```
def asynTest = Action.async {
  val willBeInt = Future {
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    100
  }

  // note you will probably need to
  // import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  // to be able to call `map` here
  willBeInt map { value =>
    Ok(s"Value = $value")
  } recover {
    case e: Throwable => InternalServerError(e.toString)
  }
}
```

For some extra reading, check out [the docs for `Future`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future), and [the docs for `Action`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action)

Comment: Ok(s"Value = $i") is typo too

Comment: Whoopsie, I had written it with `i` instead of `value` then decided to change it to make it closer to OP's original snippet.. guess I missed half of it.